# mysql replace last characters in string if matched

Tags: mysql, replace, tags

I have a table that has some rogue tags that need replacing

The offending string ends `<tr>` and needs replacing with `</table>`

Not all record are affected, so I need to find these and then replace them

Our skills using Update Replace Where are limited as the characters are not unique within the string but their position is, ie the last 4 characters

Have tried using

```
UPDATE table
SET field
REPLACE (RIGHT(field,4),</table>)
```

but suspec this is over simplified (and also fails)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this:

```
UPDATE table
SET field=concat(left(field,length(field) -4),'</table>')
```

Comment: that is spot on - thank you, used it with this to find and replace the offending code

    UPDATE table 
    SET field=concat(left(field,length(field) -4),'</table>') WHERE
    products_description LIKE '% </td></tr><tr>'

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation in which needed to replace '_' from end of the `transaction` number field, where there where more than one occurrences of `_` in field. Example: 20161124_C_BGN_5570.77_ & 20161121_C_HRK_1502360000__

**Solution:**

```
UPDATE temp 
SET transaction = LEFT(transaction, LENGTH(transaction) -1) 
WHERE RIGHT(transaction, 1) = '_';
```

// in case of double underscore (__)

```
UPDATE temp 
SET transaction = LEFT(transaction, LENGTH(transaction) -2) # WHERE id = xxx WHERE RIGHT(transaction, 2) = '__';
```

Comment: how would you update your values that end with '101' and needs replacing with '102'. but the varchar length varies. Just last 3 is the focus point